# How to implement community wiki until we have mods?

Tags: discussion, support

We have several questions that really need to be made into community wiki questions, but this is currently a feature of SE available only to moderators. (The [users listed as mods](https://writers.stackexchange.com/users?tab=oldest) also don't have any activity showing on their profiles yet.)

How do we turn questions into community wiki? Should we tag them until such time as we have a mechanism in place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every site receives a pretty substantial group of Moderators from day one (I'm counting about 10 out of the ~130 users on this site are Moderators right now). In about two weeks, you'll receive another group of Moderators under the [Pro Tem program](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

Even without profile "activity," Moderators are able to watch and act on flags. And flags don't go away if someone doesn't act on them right away. Some issues are just better left in the queue until the "community" moderators can come on board.

If a question needs to be made Community Wiki, flag it. Please do not usurp the tagging system for things like that. [Meta tagging is discouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) and you don't want to set that type of example for incoming users.